# Conditional Join: don't join on null

Tags: mysql, join

I have relationships that might not necessarily exist (they could be optional i.e. null); for example, a image may not have an address so it may be null.

I am unsure how to not return all null values.

Is there some condition I can put in place on the join that says if the address is null don't do a join and don't return all the null columns?

```
SELECT im.title, im.alias_title, im.description, im.main_image, im.hits, 
    im.show_comment, im.created_on, im.date_taken, im.account_type_id,
    c.make, c.model, ad.address_line_1, ad.address_line_2, 
    spc.state_province_county, tvc.town_village_city, co.country, 
    ge.latitude, ge.longitude, ge.zoom, ge.yaw, ge.pitch, 
    us.first_name, us.surname, us.user_set_online, ut.username,
    ut.account_type_id, aty.`type`, ufy.realname, ufy.location, 
    ufy.location, ufy.account_type_id
FROM image im 
    INNER JOIN user us 
            ON im.user_id = us.id
     LEFT JOIN user_type ut 
            ON us.id = ut.user_id
     LEFT JOIN user_flickr_youtube ufy 
            ON ut.id = ufy.user_type_id  
     LEFT JOIN account_type aty 
            ON ut.account_type_id =aty.id
     LEFT JOIN address ad 
            ON im.address_id = ad.id
     LEFT JOIN state_province_county spc 
            ON ad.state_province_county_id = spc.id
     LEFT JOIN town_village_city tvc 
            ON ad.town_village_city_id =tvc.id
     LEFT JOIN country co 
            ON ad.country_id =co.id
     LEFT JOIN geolocation ge 
            ON im.geolocation_id = ge.id
     LEFT JOIN camera c 
            ON im.camera_id = c.id
WHERE im.alias_title = 'test' 
    AND im.approved = 'Yes' 
    AND im.visible = '1'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I don't think i get it. If you have a SQL query, you also have projection, which means that you have to choose what columns you want to select (or *). So, in your case you want to conditionally project columns from the query? The result would have a dynamic number of columns returned, is that so?

Comment: yes if address_id is null in image table i dont need to know all the columns from the address table as they will all be null to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some condition i can put in place on the join that says if the address is null dont do a join and dont bring me back all the null columns

Yes; you can run a `JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`. But that won't simply exclude the address if it is NULL, it will ignore the whole row altogether.

Usually this kind of situation is either handled by supplying a default value, possibly empty, for example directly in MySQL

```
SELECT
...COALESCE(ad.address_line_1,'(no address)') AS address_line_1,
   COALESCE(ad.address_line_2,'')             AS address_line_2, ...
```

or it is handled by the application:

```
if row['address_line_1']:
   result = result + ("<td class=\"address\">%s</td>" % ( row['address_line_1'] ))
...
```

This also because a query could potentially return not one record, but several, and of these, some might have a NULL colum and some might not.

**UPDATE**

There is a way, but it's likely to make milk go sour in cows fifty miles downrange.

This is a proof of concept, on a MUCH smaller query and table, and takes advantage of the possibility of dynamically building a query.

First of all we have our query `WHERE` condition, here represented by "id = 1". We want to have the `name` column if the `name` column is not NULL.

```
SELECT @address := COALESCE(MIN(',name'),'') FROM client WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND id = 1;
```

This will return an empty string if the selected column is NULL. Otherwise it will return a comma and the name of that column.

This is the statement that in your case will be humongous, given your query. It contains the same `WHERE` as before, without the request that the name be NULL. And the field list is now dynamic.

```
SELECT @string := CONCAT('SELECT id', @address, ' FROM client WHERE id = 1');
```

Except that `@string` is, well, a string. To execute it as a query we do

```
PREPARE query FROM @string;
EXECUTE query;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;
```

How this might interact with your application, I do not dare fathom. I have tried an implementation in PHP on an expendable VM :-), cycling between the values of 1 and 3 (one row has a NULL name, one hasn't).

```
<?php
        // Connect to this VM's local DB
        mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db('test');

        foreach(array(1, 3) as $id)
        {
                mysql_query("SELECT @address := COALESCE(MIN(',name'),'') FROM client WHERE name IS NOT NULL AND id = $id;");
                mysql_query("SELECT @string := CONCAT('SELECT id', @address, ' FROM client WHERE id = ', $id);");
                mysql_query("PREPARE query FROM @string;");
                $exec = mysql_query("EXECUTE query;");
                while($tuple = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec))
                {
                        print implode(" | ", $tuple) . "\n";
                }
                mysql_query("DEALLOCATE PREPARE query;");
        }
?>
```

The answer seems to indicate it's working:

```
1 | Rossi
3
```

(I wouldn't have been surprised if it returned something like *'Ia! Cthulhu fhtagn!'*).

Comment: i want to return image irrespective just dont want to return null columns from address if address is null in image table- there no way round this then?

Comment: Nope, if you are selecting a column in the query, it will return with or without value (null).

Comment: The consensus seems to be there is not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489601/conditional-columns-mysql-query -- but let me think about it

Comment: Turns out there is a way. Sort of. I would advise against it, though. See updated answer.